# Stop the Application in Driver when Worker is failed

Tags: java, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

There is Application, that is run at Driver.

This  Application initialize SparkSession:

```
   SparkSession sparkSession;
```

And UDF function registered:

```
     session.udf().register(BASE64_CLOB_DECODER, (UDF2<String, String, String>) (base64, charSet) -> decode2String(base64, charSet), DataTypes.StringType);
```

Application runs operations in SparkSession: read, transform and write dataframe.

During trasform-operations udf-function called. Result of transformation is used in spark-write operations then. This is the realization of this function:

```
 public String decode2String(String inputString, String charSet) {
        try {
              byte[] byteArray =  decode2Bytes(inputString);
              return new String(byteArray, charSet);
           } catch (Exception e) {
                sparkSession.close();
                // sparkSession.stop();
                throw new DecodeFormatException(charSet);
           }
        }
```

The problem is that, when some exception is throwed by this function, the execution at worker is stopped with Exception:

```
          org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: executor 2): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows. …
          Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function ….
          Caused by: exceptions.decode.DecodeFormatException:
```

But the Application in Driver **continues to work**. Application **is hanging**, as a result.

Neither sparkSession.close() nor sparkSession.stop() help to stop Application.
Is there any way to stop Application programmicaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to close your SparkSession from inside of a UDF. This does not make sense, as that UDF is executed by the executors.

It should be the driver that closes your SparkSession.

It seems like you do not want your `decode2String` UDF to fail even once. To this end, try setting:

- `spark.stage.maxConsecutiveAttempts` to 1
- `spark.task.maxFailures` to 1

Then you can catch the exception in your driver, so not inside of your `decode2String` UDF but right after and call `sparkSession.stop()` there. By the way, `sparkSession.close()` does not exist :)